# How to implement a VOIP service on the server?

Tags: http, voip

I know my question is broad, but I have no clue where to start my research.

How can one implement VoIP on a server? I am fairly certain it does not use the http/https protocol. If so, what standard/famous protocols one can use? are there any open-source ones? What are good references to start working on that?

Comment: You could use [AGI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/AGI-1.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by looking at the SIP,RTP and RTCP protocols. I believe they form a minimalistic set of required protocols for VoiP

Some relevant open source projects:

http://www.fsf.org/campaigns/priority-projects/priority-projects/highpriorityprojects#Replaceskype

"There are a number of such programs, such as Ekiga, Twinkle, Coccinella, QuteCom, and Jitsi. Unfortunately, these programs only replace some of Skype's functionality, and only in some situations. WebRTC has a mission to enable rich, high quality, Real-Time Communications (RTC) applications to be developed in the browser via simple Javascript APIs and HTML5. Developers should consider helping free software VoIP and video, chat, and multimedia communications projects."

Comment: When two users are using VoIP (say Skype), are the users connected directly to each other, or are the packets sent through the server?

Comment: They don't have to be connected to each other directly, but they can be. Skype is proprietary software; there's no easy way to find out how it does what it does.